# p5.js: How can I access elements in a for() loop to rollover?

Tags: javascript, html, hover, p5.js

I'm working on a interactive text analysis website and I currently have a for() loop running through an array of lines in a .txt file. Each line generates a rectangle. It works well but I need to be able to mouseOver/rollover each square to then print the text line on the web page. Essentially I just need to write something that says if mouseX + mouseY are on-top of a rectangle, append lines[i] to a paragraph in the html.

I'm still getting to grips with p5.js and how to jump between my sketch.js and the html page. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Current code

```
var book = [];
var lines = [];
var term1 = [];
var term2 = [];
var size;
var x;
var y;

function preload() {
    book = loadStrings("data/01.txt");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100, 100);
    lines = splitTokens(book[0], ".?");
    term1 = ["photography", "Photography", "PHOTOGRAPHY"];
    term2 = ["art", "Art", "ART"];
    size = 10;
    x = 40;
    y = 50;
    noLoop();
    noStroke();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    background(0, 0, 100);
}

function draw() {
    background(0, 0, 100);

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {    
        x += size;
        if (x >= windowWidth - 50) {
            x = 40;
            y += size;
        }

        // contains term 1 and term 2
        if ((lines[i].indexOf(term1[0]) > 0 || lines[i].indexOf(term1[1]) > 0 || lines[i].indexOf(term1[02]) > 0) && (lines[i].indexOf(term2[0]) > 0 || lines[i].indexOf(term2[1]) > 0 || lines[i].indexOf(term2[2]) > 0)) {
            fill(37, 87, 100);
        } else if (lines[i].indexOf(term1[0]) > 0 || lines[i].indexOf(term1[1]) > 0 || lines[i].indexOf(term1[2]) > 0) {
            fill(333, 61, 94);
        } else if (lines[i].indexOf(term2[0]) > 0 || lines[i].indexOf(term2[1]) > 0 || lines[i].indexOf(term2[2]) > 0) {
            fill(203, 71, 98);
        } else {
            fill(0, 0, 95);
        }

        rect(x, y, size/2, size/2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your problem up into smaller steps.

**Step 1:** Can you write code that determines when the mouse is over a rectangle?

You know your rectangle's position and size, since you use that in this line:

```
rect(x, y, size/2, size/2);
```

So you can use that along with `mouseX` and `mouseY` to determine whether the mouse is over the rectangle:

```
if(mouseX > x && mouseX < x+size/2 && mouseY > y && mouseY < y+size/2){
    //do something
    fill(255, 0, 0);
}
```

If you place that line right above the `rect()` line, then any rectangles you hover over will turn red. Note that this is just an example placeholder for step 2!

**Step 2**: Can you write code that you call from Processing that interacts with the page?

You can just write JavaScript in P5.js, so you can google something like "JavaScript append to textarea" to figure out how to do that. Here's an example:

```
document.getElementById("yourIdHere").value += "your text here";
```

So if you have a text area with an id of "mousePositions", you can append to it like this:

```
function draw(){
   document.getElementById("mousePositions").value += (mouseX + ", " + mouseY);
   //rest of your code
```

**Step 3:** Only when you get each of those smaller examples working perfectly by themselves, then you think about combining them.

You have code that detects a rollover, and you have code that modifies the webpage from Processing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had to end up using a different method to append the text to a paragraph but it's working now, thanks! I only have one problem now, which is that while the for loop is generating a nice grid of squares, as y+=10 pushes down the rows as they hit the edge of the window, the entire group of squares falls down the page with each frame and complete loop. Is there any way I can keep the entire bunch of squares still without noLoop()?

Comment: Nevermind, fixed! Forgot to state x = value and y = value at the start of the DRAW loop, which then informed the for() loop. This whole time it was only in setup(), so only updated once. Thanks again!